# calculating uniformity for a 64 by 64 image

Tags: python, image, numpy

I am fairly new to python and to programming in genral. I've been trying to calculate uniformity for an image using python and its libraries. The image is in a 64 by 64 matrix padded with zeros, because detector size is smaller than the "image". Before calculating, I have to smooth the image using weighted kernel: ([[1,2,1], [2,4,2], [1,2,1]]).

But before smoothing I have to set the values of border pixels accordingly:

1. Any pixels at the edge of useful field of view (ufov) containing containing less than 75% of mean value in central field of view (75% of ufov), shall be set to zero.
2. Pixels which have at least one of their four directly abbuted neighbors containing zero, shall be set to zero.
3. The weighting factor for a pixel outside the analysed area in 9 point filter, shall be zero.

I've used ma.masked_equal to exclude the padded area. But I am having troubles to apply above conditions. Not to mention applying them only to the edge of the useful field of view.

As English is not my first language, I hope I've explained understandably. Otherwise I aplogize.

```
import numpy as np
import numpy.ma as ma
import scipy
from scipy import ndimage

#ufov = useful field of view - non-zero elements
#cfov = central field of view - in this example 50% of ufov

img = ([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 0, 1, 0, 8, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 1, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 6, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 6, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])

img = ma.masked_equal(img, 0) #mask zeros

axis_0 = ma.notmasked_edges(img,0) #start/end masked pixel value along axis=0
axis_1 = ma.notmasked_edges(img,1) #start/end masked pixel value along axis=1

xstart = min(axis_1[0][1]) #start along x axis -rows (last masked pixel)
xend = max(axis_1[1][1]) #end along x axis -rows (last masked pixel)

ystart = min(axis_0[0][0]) #start along y axis -columns (last masked pixel)
yend = max(axis_0[1][0]) #end along y axis -columns (last masked pixel)

ufov = img[ystart:yend+1, xstart:xend+1] #ufov sliced along the masked array edge

#cfov is 50% of ufov(sliced from ufov)

cfovystart = int((ufov.shape[0] - ufov.shape[0] * 0.5)/2)
cfovyend = int(ufov.shape[0] - cfovystart)
cfovxstart = int((ufov.shape[1] - ufov.shape[1] * 0.5)/2)
cfovxend = int(ufov.shape[1] - cfovxstart)

cfov = ufov[cfovystart:cfovyend, cfovxstart:cfovxend]

#1. condition - applied over the whole ufov (want edges)
#pixels containing less than 75% of cfov mean value are replace with 0
mean = int(cfov.mean()*0.75)

ufov[ufov < mean]=0

#2. condition
#pixels which have at least one of their four directly abbuted neighbors containing zero
#shall be set to zero ???

#3.condition
#the weighting factor for a pixel outside the analysed are in 9 point filter
#shall be zero ???


#smoothing befor calculating (but not including the 3.condition
weights = np.array([[1,2,1],
                   [2,4,2],
                   [1,2,1]])

kernel = weights*1/16

img_smth = ndimage.convolve(ufov, kernel, mode="constant", cval=0)

#then calculate the uniformity of ufov - useful field of view as follows

#max_pix = int(ufov.max())
#min_pix = int(ufov.min())

#unif_ufov = (max_pix-min_pix) / (max_pix+min_pix) * 100
```

Comment: Can you drop some code in here so we can see what you're actually trying to do?

Comment: Please give a small example (reduce your image to say 16 x16) and illustrate the conditions. Give both some data (synthetic, i.e. made up) and  some code. Very likely some of your problems can be solved with slicing. E.g. when you go through the array in x,y, you can look at the sum of neighboring pixels with  `np.sum(dat[i-1:i+2,j-1:j+2]) - dat[i,j]` etc.  Also `fov  =field of view` may not be obvious to non-optics people, so please define them. I'm assuming based on your kernel that you need to set just one row around the borders of the matrix to zero, so is fov= 14x14 for a matrix of 16x16?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I have edited my question.